# Installed djangorestframework but imports on error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I just installed `djangorestframework` on an existing app. I followed the first page of django rest framework tutorial, added my `rest_framework` to my `INSTALLED_APPS`, followed the tutorial and did `from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets` but I get an error on this line `"...\docutils\core.py", line 246 print ('\n::: Runtime settings:', file=self._stderr) SyntaxError: invalid syntax` invalid syntax at `=`.

I tried a different tutorial and it appears that any `from rest_framework` i just can't import it and gives me the same error.

I am using python 2.7.8 and django 1.10.5, and just freshly installed the djangorestframework.

I don't know where to go from here. I've searched and seemed the result is pretty limited. Any kind suggestions/directions?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the error? Perhaps its stacktrace?

Comment: My suggestion to you is to upgrade everything. Your a little outdated I am not saying that this is not fixable but it would be a good idea. Then at least you know the content is supported. I think your Django is out of date and not supported according to Django rest framework site. REST framework requires the following:

**Python** (2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7)
**Django** (1.11, 2.0, 2.1) You have **1.10.5** not **1.11**

Answer (score -2):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to a compatibility issue between Django REST framework and the Python version you're using (Python 2.7.8). Django REST framework requires Python 3.5 or later, so attempting to use it with Python 2.7.8 will likely result in syntax errors and other compatibility problems.

To resolve this issue, you have a few options:

**Upgrade to Python 3.x:** The best solution is to upgrade your Python version to 3.5 or later. Python 2.7 has reached its end of life and is no longer maintained with updates or bug fixes. Python 3.x offers numerous improvements and new features. You'll need to migrate your codebase to Python 3.x and then install the latest version of Django and Django REST framework.

**Downgrade Django REST Framework:** If upgrading Python is not an option, you might consider using an older version of Django REST framework that is compatible with Python 2.7. Check the release notes of Django REST framework to find a version that supports Python 2.7. Keep in mind that using older versions of software might limit your access to new features and bug fixes.

**Use a Virtual Environment:** If you need to work with both Python 2 and Python 3 projects, you can use virtual environments to isolate your project's dependencies. You could create a Python 2.7 virtual environment for your existing Django project and use an older version of Django REST framework that supports Python 2.7. However, this is not a recommended long-term solution due to Python 2's end of life status.

Given that Python 2.7 and Django 1.10 are both outdated and no longer actively supported, I strongly recommend upgrading to Python 3.x and a more recent version of Django and Django REST framework. This will not only resolve your current issue but also ensure that you're working with a more secure and up-to-date environment.